# Visual Studio for Java?

Tags: java, visual-studio

Did anybody have the idea to create a Visual Studio extension for Java ?
Somebody wrote an article here:
http://www.improve.dk/blog/2007/09/29/compiling-java-in-visual-studio

But nobody seems to have the idea of using the free visual studio isolated shell to create an IDE for Java?

Answer (score 4):

Good question. There are some plugins for VS that allow production of other code, such as [SapphireSteel Software's Amethyst](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Adobe-Flex-Development-in-Visual) (allowing Flex development with VS) so it's only natural to ask if there was a plugin for a language as popular as Java.

After searching around the web for a bit (damn NerdSniping :P) I found something very interesting: [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130), a MSIL to Java Bytecode crosscompiler that allows running VB and C# 3.0 webapplications on Java Application Servers and also extends VS to work with Java Bytecode (debugging capabilities, IntelliSense for Java classes, etc).

Perhaps someone else has some firsthand experience with this product or could give some more information regarding the actual capabilities of the crosscompiler.

Comment: Grasshoper is an interesting idea, I intend to try it. But I also need to be able to code in java traditionally so my question is still unanswered ;)

Comment: Thanks for Amethystfor adobe air I'm also interested thet's seems great and ... free !

Answer (score 1):

You can also use J# to write your java code in VS. Dont see the real point of having a java plugin?

Comment: J# is not supported any more by MS.

Answer (score 1):

People would probably rather spend time improving Eclipse or Netbeans.

Comment: Not for people who are used to VS and obliged to cope with Java sometimes like the guy above and myself :)

Comment: but if eclipse can offer the equivalence of VS I don't care using eclipse that's why I asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694273/what-eclipse-plugins-would-give-the-equivalent-of-visual-studio-2010-ultimate

Comment: Are you sure it can reverse-engineer code to uml sequence diagram ? as far as I guess it can only draw uml sequence diagram.

Comment: @BalusC your link doesn't work anymore - 404 ;(

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft don't like Java.  Those who do, write IDE's in Java.

Comment: Sun attacked Microsoft for J# for not being Java that's why they created C# instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a plugin that supports the JAVA language in Visual Studio:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93

Answer (score 0):

Answers to the same question here:

http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.384449.7

... except nobody can't really answer because there is none indeed !

Anybody realize there is a HUGE Business Opportunity to do so ? Thoough Mainsoft has done a great job at recompiling .net for j2ee, they would have made more $$$ by just creating an ide fully for java.

Comment: Nobody that seriously develops using the Java platform is going to pay for  Visual Studio and/or some addon when there are perfectly viable and more Java-oriented IDEs available free of charge.